# IDEA 2021 will not allow to download Open JDK 11 in the Project Settings dialog box

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to download **Oracle OpenJDK version 11** through my **IDEA 2021.2.2** Community Edition but it won't work!

I'm using **Project Settings/Platform Settings/SDKs/+/Download JDK** dialog box. Whenever I choose **version 11 and vendor Oracle OpenJDK**, the options in the dialog box **automatically switch to version 17 Oracle OpenJDK**. However, there's no problem if I choose any other vendor (eg Zulu, AdobeOpenJDK, etc.) for version 11.
It is as if IDEA was saying it makes no sense to download version 11 for Oracle OpenJDK.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that there's **already** OpenJDK version 11.0.12 in my IDEA installation directory
IDEA-C/ch-0/212.5284.40/jbr/bin?!

In IDEA's docs I found that I should **not** use this bundled JDK for my projects and I should install **a standalone JDK**.
So why does IDEA not let me download another Oracle OpenJDK version 11
but version 17 is ok?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle OpenJDK as a distribution release is new with Java 17.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for the old java.net releases. They're archived [here](https://jdk.java.net/archive/). But you should probably prefer more maintained releases in general.